# Magento 1.7.0.2 - Display Image Category above 2 columns left page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

My category product page has this layout :  2 columns with left sidebar.

When i set my category image it goes up just in 1 column ( category page ).

How can i make for the category image to go above both columns, category page and sidebar ?

Comment: That image is loaded within the `template/catalog/category/view.phtml`, which is loaded inside of the main column.  You could use some CSS positioning tricks to move the image outside of the main column, or you could modify your `template/page/2columns-left.phtml` to load in the category object, and retrieve the image there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The category banner(image) comes from `template/catalog/category/view.phtml` like this

```
$_imgHtml   = '';
if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
  $_imgHtml = '<div class="category-image-container"><div class="category-image-container-inner"><p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></p></div></div>';
    $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
}
```

first comment this

Then in `template/page/2columns-left.phtml` between`<div class="main">` and `<div class="col-left"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>`

write the category banner code

```
<?php   
        $_category  = Mage::registry('current_category');
        if($_category){
         $_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');

            $_imgHtml   = '';
            if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
           echo   $_imgHtml = '<div class="category-image-container1"><div class="category-image-container-inner"><p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></p></div></div>';
                $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
            }
        }
        ?>
```

This will show the category banner above the left column and the content.

Comment: I am glad that i could help you :)